# clouds reflective property

Tags: visible-light, everyday-life

I am a private pilot and see some beautiful clouds in all forms and patterns up in the sky.

I wonder what causes some of the clouds to be so shiny, reflecting such an intense light that it's hard to look at them, and some other are rather lifeless and opaque?
some clouds seem to have a well defined boundary surface which is highly reflective under favorable conditions.

Sometimes I see the shadow of my plane skimming the surface of cloud so clear as if it were a solid surface!
I know a little bit about meteorology and different clouds and weather fronts but this question comes from purely visual aspect of clouds. Thanks.

Comment: Clouds will look better when you have the sun behind you... which is when you see the shadow of your plane. Could you comment on whether that is a "preferred direction" for seeing beautiful clouds, in your experience?

Comment: I fly just for fun and mostly around southern California which has a mild weather. there are seasonal clouds which are called marine layer around here, those are thin and low density. so they don't demonstrate hi contrast defined boundaries. but sometimes there are patches of clouds a few miles in dimension, very dense and continuous surface, highly reflective. these are either rising cumulus clouds or just the patches left over after rain. regardless my favorite angle is the geometry of sun and the surface of cloud in a way that the surface of cloud is angled as a mirror positioned well!

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the transparency of clouds, I think the size of water drops and ice crystals forming the clouds matters a lot. Larger size of those microparticles will tend to make the cloud's boundary well defined and looks bright white. Opposite, the cloud will look transparent and grey. Light can be reflected and scattered so many ways from and in a cloud that when illuminated directly it ends up looking an fairly white. How much and how strong of those reflection and scattering is determines if the boundary is clear or not.

There are many factors determining the size of water drops and ice crystals. This includes temperature, pressure, dusts in sky and so on.

Other reference: [this article](http://optics.kulgun.net/Cloud-Colour/).